# array_push and >= not working

Tags: php, arrays

Heyo! I've never knew this actually but the following method doesn't seem to work properly.

```
array_push($items[$key], 'price' => 100);
```

How can I push it in an array so it displays,
`{'price':100, 'moredata':1231}`

What am I missing?

Comment: `'price' => 100` is not a *value* you can push to an array. I think you just want `$items[$key]['price'] = 100`. This is mentioned in the first comment on the manual page ~ http://php.net/manual/function.array-push.php#108118

Comment: @Phil damn, why did I never know this :/. Thank you!

Comment: Because [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) isn't always fun to read :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify a key with `array_push`.

Fortunately, most of the time* when people use `array_push` it isn't actually necessary.

```
$items[$key]['price'] = 100
```

<sub>*at least most of the time in Stack Overflow questions</sub>

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I'll accept the answer in 10 minutes.